# Get path of current file in jupyter notebook R (irkernel)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

I am looking for a way to get the path of current working notebook on jupyter notebook irkernel in order to do `setwd()` easier.

Using reticulate and call python os does not work. Although it works in a python notebook.

```
library(reticulate)
os <- import("os")
os$listdir(".")
```

Comment: Why not just use `getwd()`? There's also the `list.files()` and `list.dirs()` functions: https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/list.files.html